# Would it be useful to make the "You need X rep to take care of this review queue" message friendlier?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I just noticed that this message, which appears when you try to [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) a queue for which you don't have enough reputation:

> You need at least [insert minimum rep here] reputation to review [insert review queue's name here].

can be replaced with this message, which is more welcoming to new-ish users:

> Thank you for your interest in [insert review queue's name here]. Once you reach [insert minimum rep here] reputation, you will be able to [insert review queue's description here].

So for example, the "Your rep is too low" message for [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) would look like this:

> Thank you for your interest in Close Votes. Once you reach 3000 reputation, you will be able to vote whether or not to close questions with close votes.

Doing so would make the site (slightly) friendlier and easier to use, but on the other hand a user with >500 rep should know how SO works, at least minimally. How useful would such a change be?

Comment: While I think the intention is good, the solution is way too long and makes the tooltip less skimmable (and therefore less useful).

Comment: Should a stop sign say *"please stop here, thanks"*?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all useful. I'm not sure you've noticed, but SO (and especially Meta SO) is populated by a bunch of surly people who [hate politeness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/194720) almost as much as they [hate fun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/194720) (yes, I know those are both from Meta SE, but they're just as bad).

All kidding aside, I don't think that many people are trying to access reviews for which they lack the appropriate reputation. Thus, for those few intrepid souls like yourself who stumble upon them, a simple message is sufficient.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah, I got confused between getting rep for suggesting an edit and getting rep for reviewing a suggested edit. Removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply make a message more polite by adding words to it that are commonly used in polite discussion. There is still no person behind those hollow words to give them meaning.

Lets also better describe the target audience of this request; its not new users in general. Its new users who somehow are negatively impacted by neutrality - a lack of politeness or rudeness. What kind of users will those likely be I wonder? I am not going to go into details but they're not exactly going to be the crowd that a site like SO caters to.

Because its a site with a business attitude, it provides information and services that people can consume - and has a moderation system that requires people to have thick skin. There is no easing your way into the usage of SO - you're expected to be a sane human being who can rationalise what they see and look for guidance when they don't understand - guidance that is available aplenty on Stack in the form of the tour, the help centre, meta sites and chat rooms.

As to the messages, the way they are phrased is concise and to the point - perfectly neutral. That makes them exactly right to me.

**TL;DR**
If a lack of false politeness is in any way a negative experience for new users, well then I hope they adapt sooner rather than later. But never the other way around.